# Ошибка при выводе матрицы в функции

Tags: c++, матрицы

У меня проблема с умножением матриц , в функции gaussdet, примерно на 147 строчке кода у меня вызывается функция multimass которая умножает две матрицы и выдает результат произведения , в моем случае первая матрица 4 на 4, вторая 4 на 1 , при выводе их на экран проблем нет , а при выводе результирующей (в программе матрица X) со второго элемента выходит за пределы памяти , не могу разобраться почему

P.S когда будете запускать , может выходить сообщение : Problem on diagonal , это просто проверка на нулевой элемент на диагонали , если он есть то программа заканчивается (ВЫВОД ФУНКЦИИ НАПИСАЛ В КОНЦЕ ПРОГРАММЫ(ЕСЛИ ЧТО) , НО ПРОБЛЕМА ЕЩЕ НЕ РЕШЕНА)
Gaussdet(A, T, size) - ТАК ВЫГЛЯДИТ;
КАК ВЫГЛЯДИТ ОШИБКА :

```
T=
  1.00   0.12  -0.24   0.06
-10.00   1.00  10.29  -3.83
 -0.60  -0.24   1.00  -0.13
 -0.38  -2.35   3.30   1.00


B=
 -1.18
-133.32
  5.12
 47.83


X= -4.72
58272643341906563227001172011003450238171962660182166064623285546474534185353454120209369334948557897585914528605758787177320684741845861550522368.00
  0.00
 -0.00
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
#define clean system("cls");
#define next cout<<endl;
int ShowMtx(double** A, int size)//вывод с выравниванием
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size + 1; j++)
        {
            cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(6) << A[i][j] << " ";
        }
        next
    }
    return 0;
}
int ShowMtx1(double** A, int size,int size1)//вывод с выравниванием
{
    if (size1 != size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size1; j++)
            {
                cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(6) << A[i][j] << " ";
            }
            next
        }
        next
    }
    else 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(6) << A[i][j] << " ";
            }
            next
        }
        next
    
    }
        return 0;
}

int MultiMass(double** T, double** B, double** X, int size)//умножение
{
    cout << "T=" << endl; ShowMtx1(T, size,size); next
        cout << "B=" << endl; ShowMtx1(B,size,1); next
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            {
                X[i][j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
                {
                    X[i][j] += T[i][j] * B[j][i];
                }
            }
        }
    cout << "X="; ShowMtx1(X,size,1);
    return 0;
}
int Gaussdet(double** A, double**T, int size)
{
double eps;
cout << "Enter the epsilon" << endl;
cin >> eps;// минимальный модуль элемента матрицы //
while ((eps >= 1) || (eps <= 0)) { cout << "Error , enter the epsilon(<1,>0)" << endl; cin >> eps; }
bool isNull = false;
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
{
    if (A[i][i] == 0)
    {
        isNull = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (isNull)
{
    cout << "Problem on diagonal" << endl;//если находим нуль на главной диагонали, то выводим сообщение  об ошибке
    return 0;
}
//проверка на нулевую строку
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        int schet = 0, schet1 = 0;
        if (A[i][j] < eps) schet += 1;
        
        if ((schet == size - 1) || (schet1 == size - 1))
        {
            cout << "Nulevaya stroka,det=0" << endl;
        }
    }
}

for (int d = 0; d < size - 1; d++)//прямой ход
{
    for (int i = d + 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        double tmp = double(A[i][d] / A[d][d]);
        for (int j = 0; j < size + 1; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = A[i][j] - A[d][j] * tmp;
            T[i][j] = T[i][j] - T[d][j] * tmp;

        }
    }
}
next
int columns = size + 1;
for (int k = 1; k < size; k++)
{
    int indexDop = size - k;
    for (int i = size - k - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        double tmp = A[i][indexDop] / A[indexDop][indexDop];
        for (int j = indexDop; j < columns; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = A[i][j] - A[indexDop][j] * tmp;
            T[i][j] = T[i][j] - T[indexDop][j] * tmp;
        }
    }
}
ShowMtx(A, size); next
cout << "A^(-1)=" << endl; ShowMtx1(T,size,size);
int det = 1;//вычисление определителя
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) det *= A[i][i];
cout << "det(A)=" << det << endl;
// X-матрица решений
double** B = new double* [size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    B[i] = new double[1];
for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    B[j][0] = A[j][size]; cout <<"B="<< B[j][0] << "\n";
}

double** X = new double* [size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    X[i] = new double[1];
cout << "X=T^(-1)*B" << endl;
MultiMass(T, B, X, size);
return 0;
}

int Summmtx(double** A, double** B, double** C, int size)//вычисление суммы матриц
{
    cout << "A="; ShowMtx(A, size);
    cout << "B="; ShowMtx(B, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {// результат суммирования матриц в новую матрицу
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
        }
        next
    }
    cout << "C="; ShowMtx(C, size);
    return 0;
}
void deleteMtx(double** A, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; i++)
    {
        delete[] A[i];
    }
    delete[] A;
}
void deleteMtx1(double** B, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        delete[] B[i];
    }
    delete[] B;
}
int main()
{
    int rows, size, choice;
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tInput matrix A" << endl;//ввод матрицы A
    cout << "Enter the size of matrix A (>0,<=15)" << endl;
    cin >> size;
    while ((size < 0) || (size > 15)) { cout << "Enter the size of matrix A again" << endl; cin >> size; }
    //выход за пределы диапазона//
    double** A = new double* [size];//матрица A
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        A[i] = new double[size + 1];
    }
        label:
    cout << "1-Randomly(matrix A)\n2-Manually(matrix A) " << endl;//автоматически или вручную//
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        srand(time(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size + 1; j++)
            {
                A[i][j] = rand() % 20;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size + 1; j++)
            {
                cout << "A[" << i << "," << j << "]= ";
                cin >> A[i][j];
            }
            next
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        goto label;
    }
    }
    ShowMtx(A,size);
    double** C = new double* [size];// C - копия матрицы А
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        C[i] = new double[size + 1]; C[i] = A[i];
    }
    double** T = new double* [size];// T-для обратной матрицы
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        T[i] = new double[size + 1];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)//заполнение смежной матрицы T
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (i == j) { T[i][j] = 1; }
            else { T[i][j] = 0; }
        }
    }
    Gaussdet(A, T, size);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько проблем.

1. В функции умножения матрицы есть цикл с переменной `k`, но она у вас нигде не используется. То есть неправильно перемножаются матрицы.
2. В том же цикле у вас написано `B[j][i]` хотя столбцов у вас в матрице `B` всего один. Тут то вы и выходите за пределы матрицы.

Так же не очень понятно, если у вас столбцов у матрицы `B` ровно один, то зачем вам эта строчка `for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)`. Я так думаю на будущее.

Вот пример кода без ошибок описанных выше:

```
cout << "T=" << endl; ShowMtx1(T, size, size); next
cout << "B=" << endl; ShowMtx1(B, size, 1); next
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
    {
        X[i][j] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
        {
            X[i][j] += T[i][k] * B[k][j];
        }
    }
}
cout << "X="; ShowMtx1(X, size, 1);
```

Comment: Спасибо , что помогли